# How to create multiple resources when required by terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

We use terraform to create one project resource and other resources e.g logs, files...

```
# Create project
resource "google_project" "my_project1" {
  name       = "My Project1"
  project_id = "your-project-id"
  org_id     = "1234567"
}
```

How could we create more projects (my_project2, my_project3, my_project4...) with same or similar resources with terraform? instead of destroying and recreating the existing project?

I want every time running `terraform apply`, it will create one additional project with all resources ready and meanwhile the previous existing projects have not been modified.

P.S I do not want to use `count` or `for each` to create multiple projects for the first running, as we want only when someone asked for an additional project, we create it with terraform

Comment: "I do not want to use count" - then use for_each. Otherwise, its not possible.

Comment: Maybe some misunderstanding, if we use count or for_each, it mean we will create multiple projects when we run "terraform apply" first time. We hope to create the multiple resources one by one only when requested.

Comment: Its not possible. TF does not support such a functionality. You have to create different workspaces for each project in TF.

Comment: @Marcin, thanks for your info. So it means we have to create individual workspaces for additional  projects? e.g ```my_workspace1``` for project1, ```my_workspace2``` for project2..., then all these projects to share some common modules? thanks

Comment: To solve a similar problem, I created a workspace for each environemnt (dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4, and prod), and then a Makefile that switches to the desired workspace and then runs apply.  This allows me to make a change and apply it to one dev environment, make sure it's sane, and then apply it to other dev environments.

Comment: Got it, thanks, it means workspace could isolate the interferences among resources. One more question, if in one workspace e.g dev6, I created project6, in the project6, it has resources e.g logs based on module. If we want to only update the log module in project6 instead of other resources e.g files in project6, is it possible? thanks for your help

Comment: @fzhurd Yes, workspaces allow to separate different environments based on the same TF code-based.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform is a "desired state" declarative system, and so it isn't possible to command Terraform to create any particular imperative action. You can't directly tell Terraform to create an object: instead, you must tell Terraform that an object should exist and then Terraform itself will check whether it already created the object or not, and will plan to create it only if it wasn't already created.

For that reason, the expected way to solve your problem with Terraform is to gradually additional resource instances to your configuration, either by adding more `resource` blocks that have one instance each or by making your one `resource` block set either `count` or `for_each` to declare multiple instances with the same block. At any time your configuration should describe all of the projects that ought to currently exist; if you remove a project from the configuration then Terraform will propose to destroy it.

If you are not interested in tracking and updating existing objects over time then Terraform is not the appropriate tool for this task. Instead, you'll need to find an alternative solution which follows an imperative model where you can literally tell the software to create an object regardless of what actions were taken in the past.

[The `gcloud` CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) could be a sufficient solution to your problem, if you just need to create new projects with fixed settings you will specify explicitly each time. [`gcloud projects create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create) is the command for creating a new project:

```
gcloud projects create \
  'your-project-id' \
  --name='My Project1' \
  --organization='1234567'
```